# How to hide the entire class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, hide, .net-assembly

Lets imagine:

```
// assembly 01

abstract class Foo
{
    abstract void Bar();
}
class AdvancedFoo : Foo
{
    override void Bar() { base.Foo(); ... }
}
sealed class SuperiorFoo : AdvancedFoo
{
    override sealed void Bar() { base.Foo(); }
}
```

And then I want to reference that assembly **01** from my **02** asm and replace the intermediate base class (and only it) so the instances of a `SuperiorFoo` were acting like they are inhereting from assembly **02**'s `AdvancedFoo`.

```
// assembly 02

class AdvancedFoo : Foo
{
    override void Bar() { base.Foo(); ... }
}
```

Is there any way to do that by not rewriting the `SuperiorFoo` class declaration if the **02** assembly?

```
var supFoo = new SuperiorFoo();
supFoo.Bar(); // This one should call assembly 02's Bar();
```

Comment: Just use an interface, please

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your code? From your question, I would guess you meant for `SuperiorFoo` to inherit `AdvancedFoo` and not `Foo`.

Comment: Try to to do so: "sealed class SuperiorFoo : AdvancedFoo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the way that you are doing no, but you could possibly use composition rather than inheritance to solve your issue:

```
interface IFoo
{
    abstract void Bar();
}
class AdvancedFoo : IFoo
{
    override void Bar() { base.Foo(); ... }
}
sealed class SuperiorFoo : IFoo
{
    private IFoo _fooImplementer;

    public SuperiorFoo()
    {
        _fooImplemnter = new AbstractFoo();
    }

    public SuperiorFoo(IFoo fooImplementer)
    {
       _fooImplementer = fooImplementer;
    }

    void Bar() { _fooImplementer.Foo(); }
}
```

To call from your second assembly, you would use the second constructor, passing an instance of your new 'advancedfoo' class.

Answer (score 1):

Type forwarding can help: [Type Forwarding in the Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404275.aspx)